# Is there any way I can remove the path from set -x/+x xtrace?

Tags: bash, zsh

I am using set -x and set +x to display the variables from my service, that are loaded from a file.

How can I remove the folder path, that's super long from set -x?

```
/mnt/d/repos/test1/src/services/deployment/services/sample/ .....> CLUSTER=2
```

I heard that there are options to trap into the debugger, but no clue.

thanks for the help!

Comment: If you use `set -x`, you want to debug, what your program is executing, so I don't see a point in hiding part of this information; but the log is written to stderr, so you can catch this and apply any tranformation you like.

Comment: I see your point. I am trying actually to use set -x as a hack to print some executions and not for debugging. I don't know other way to do it, and that's why I am trying this way.

Comment: You put a hack in, you get a hack out. Don't misuse features, but specify what you would like to achieve in the end, and we can maybe find here on SO a solution, which is less of a hack.

Comment: What I would like to achieve is a simple way to print all my environment variables, that I load using "source env.sh". The problem is using env or typeset commands give me all the extra that's in hundreds, so with  set -e in front of the file I can get all the variables that I set, but the path as well. If you know any way to achieve this scenario let me know, glad to learn it.

Comment: I guess you want to include all those variables which you **modify**. I would then do a `printenv|sort` before sourcing, and store the result (easiest in a temporary file), and do the same afterwards, and then run a `sdiff` between the two. This would break if you have values containing newlines. If this is the case, I would then simply store than unsorted, though with long lists, it may become tedious to read.